# textarea is not posted in $_POST

Tags: php, html, forms, function, error-handling

I have a simple form with a `textarea` field inside it and when posting, the `textarea` is not posted to the target page. I have tried many solutions on the web but none of them worked. Any idea how to fix it ?

HTML:

```
<form action="new_page.php" method="post" id="userform">

    <p>Content:<br />
    <textarea name="content" rows="15" cols="80" form="usrform">Enter your text</textarea>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create page"/>
   </form>
```

PHP in new_page.php:

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($_POST["content"]);
echo $content;
```

Comment: do a var_dump($_POST) on that page, anything?

Comment: @Jessica Yes, I see all fields except the textarea!

Comment: form="usrform" : for what is that?

Answer (score 9):

Remove  `form="usrform"` from your textarea and your code will work.

[or]

Renaming `usrform` on your textarea to `userform` will also work.

Comment: Because `usrform` is an invalid form reference , since your form id is named as `userform`

Comment: @MaherNabeel Notice the missing `e`?

Answer (score 3):

### Quick fix

Remove the `form="usrform"` from the textarea

OR,

change it to `form="userform"` to match the ID you have set on your form

### So, what is the form attribute?

The `form` attribute (introduced in HTML5) allows you to specify exactly which forms the current element should be related to. You can add multiple values by separating them with a space, indicating the element belongs to multiple forms.

This allows you to have form elements outside of the form itself. If you assign the forms ID to the form attribute, it will be submitted in the forms data.

**NB** This is *not* supported in IE

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_form.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Just remove form="usrform" from textarea && your code will work.

    <form action="new_page.php" method="post" id="userform">

        <p>Content:<br />
        <textarea name="content" rows="15" cols="80">Enter your text</textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create page"/>
       </form>

You can get value from textarea like this.

<?php    
$content = htmlspecialchars($_POST["content"]);
    echo $content;
?>
```

Thanks!