# Textarea wont set $_POST

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, textarea

```
<textarea name="pageeditor" id="tbMsg" style="height:350px;width:100%;"></textarea>
```

is the code to my textarea.

It doesn't submit (wont set $_POST['pageeditor']) but it will if I do:

```
<textarea name="pageeditor" id="tbMsg" style="height:350px;width:100%;">TEXT HERE</textarea>
```

which doesn't make any sense to me. It doesn't submit any text I type in on the page, but will if I hard code it into the page.

any ideas?

Comment: can you paste your form code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [textarea is not posted in $\_POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20865334/textarea-is-not-posted-in-post)

Comment: It looks like you are using an editor with this textarea field which not setting the entered text to the original textarea field??

Comment: you're correct, any ideas how to fix it? (I'm using an editor)

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. I forgot to add an onclick event to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to be displaying the `textarea` text that I enter.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);

echo $_POST['pageeditor'];
echo "</pre>";
?>
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="pageeditor" id="tbMsg" style="height:350px;width:100%;"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="form_submit"> Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>

<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo $_POST['textarea'];
    }

 ?>

</p>

<form method="post">
    <textarea name="textarea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```